# Window.localstorage not working well?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So I got a certain element in my HTML with the following attributes (I create the element with a document ready function)

```
    a_elem.setAttribute("href", "kitchen.html"); 
    a_elem.setAttribute("onclick", "passId(event, this)");
```

So what I want to do is to pass an ID to the kitchen.html. What I do is the following with the passId function:

```
function passId(event, aelem){
    console.log("EEMMM ESTOYYY ");
    var roomname = aelem.closest("figure").querySelector("figcaption").innerHTML;
    console.log("Voy a bbuscar con roomname = " + roomname);
     api.rooms.getRooms().done(function(data) {
        $.each(data, function(i, item){
            if(item.name == roomname){
                var room_id = item.id;
                console.log("FOUND IT, ID is " + room_id);
                window.localStorage.clear();
                window.localStorage.setItem("room_id", room_id);
                window.location.href = 'kitchen.html';
                }
        });
     });
}
```

And then in kitchen.html I need to use that ID, but turns out it's sometimes picked up way too late (or that's what I think) and anomalies occur:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var roomid = window.localStorage.getItem("room_id");
    window.localStorage.clear();
    api.rooms.getRoom(roomid).done(function(data){
    ...
    });
});
```

Comment: Use `addEventListener()` (or jQuery), not `setAttribute()`.

Comment: What is the problem?

Comment: "but turns out it's sometimes picked up way too late" means what?

Comment: If you want to pass the ID use `window.location.href = 'kitchen.html?room_id=' + room_id;` You don't need local storage to do that.

Comment: What kind of "anomalies" exactly occur? This is way too vague to even guess what the problem might be.

Comment: @JJJ The problem is that when I click on the aelem and navigates to kitchen.html, sometime no roomid is picked up and when it it goes to api.rooms.getRoom(roomid).done(function(data){ .... nothing is done because I believe the id is not loaded befora getRoom is called

Comment: @Ragnar and then how do I pick up de ID in kitchen.html ?

Comment: sounds to me that you navigate before your onclick finishes the work. you have both onclick and href to the link. you may want to change a-element to a div, since you do navigation in your onclick anyways.